# Workflow being sent from dropdown list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, development, designer-workflow, custom-list

This can't be that hard but I can't figure it out.  I have a dropdown list full of names of people that should get a notification email.  The simple way could be to create a people picker but I need for the names to be in dropdown list. I do not want the workflow to be very long because I am sending an email to every name in the dropdown.  Example.

```
    send email to Sam Sammy 
else 
send email to Dave Flex
```

Is there a way that I can keep the drop down but not have a long workflow with every name listed in the workflow?  Something that acts like a people picker?

Comment: Is your issue in creating a People dropdown? or in your workflow?

Comment: Workflow.  I do not want to have a workflow that is very long because I am putting each name in a new send email line in the workflow.  When using a people picker I can just call the column so whatever name is put in the space it will pull the name from the AD.  With a dropdown it seems that the workflow is too long.